# Did Kirito lie about being the *best* beta tester?

Tags: sword-art-online

I watched SAO on Crunchyroll, where the subtitles for episode 2 have Kirito saying:

> I made it higher than anyone else during the beta test.  The reason I knew the bosses skills is because I fought monsters with katana skills on floors far above us.

At the time, I just accepted this as "Kirito is just that good," which was born out by his skills and abilities later on in the series.  After all, *someone* had to be the best.

However, [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/13233/2139) claims he lied during that speech, and I've since checked the dubbed version, where he says

> During the beta, I made it to floors that were higher than any of the other testers.  That's a fact.  I knew about the boss 'cause I fought tons of monsters with way more sword skills on higher floors.

The implication of word choice and tone in the dub does sound like the kind of exaggerated bragging that gamers do when they're claiming preposterous things, but the subs don't convey that to me at all.

Is there any information showing whether he was *actually* lying?  Was he just a good beta tester (possibly in the lead group), or was he really significantly above everyone else?

Comment: official translations are almost always "localized" which means they butcher the original. Hopefully someone will track down the LN and find out what's what. Anyway, the point I'm making is take the dubs with a grain of salt.

Comment: @ton.yeung - that's one reason I prefer subs.  But I'm also not the most perceptive, especially when it comes to subtleties of Japanese culture, so I'm willing to accept that I just didn't pick up on it.

Comment: it's not impossible that kirito really made it higher than anyone else. during beta testing there would only be limited players and in the nature of MMO, other players might have been doing other quests on other levels when kirito got to the most recently available level in SAO and then the beta testing came to a halt.

Comment: I've checked the Japanese anime dialogue: he really does claim to have gone "ascended to where nobody else could" (rough re-translation), and the way he's speaking is consistent with arrogant bragging. He doesn't re-emphasize the truth of his statement, unlike in the dub, and the phrasing in his last sentence is a bit different. The Japanese dialogue in the first sentence is "俺はベータテスト中に、ほかの誰もとうたつできなかった　そうまでのぼった。", if that's of use to anyone. (I know this is an old question)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can think that's a lie, but not totally.

> I made it higher than anyone else during the beta test. The reason I knew the bosses skills is because I fought monsters with katana skills on floors far above us.

There are two possible interpretations of his claim:

1. *Kirito made it to higher floors than anyone else.*

   This is incorrect, because you cannot go to higher floor without defeating the boss first. And, after you defeat it, everyone else can go to the next floor through the teleport door.
2. *Kirito have more experience than others.*

   This is probably correct, because from Light Novel Volume 1 - Chapter 2:

   > The two months of beta testing were like a dream. At school I thought endlessly of my skill set, equipment, and items. I ran all the way home as soon as school ended and dived till dawn. The beta test ended in the blink of an eye. On the day my character was reset, I felt a sense of loss as if half of my actual self had been cut away.

   Because of this, you can assume that Kirito had spent a lot of time on the game,  maybe more than others. Maybe he compiled more floor map information than other players... maybe, he knew more mobs, but he couldn't know mobs or bosses from upper floors. All information which Kirito knew was also available for other beta players if they tried to view it (maybe, but unique quests were unlikely to be made public).

   There's no info about boss defeat in beta, but there probably wasn't any boss defeated by Kirito only (but that's my opinion).

Comment: +1 for the first point, i totally forgot that floors can be skipped so one doesn't actually need to track all the way. also with Beta Boss Data the Wikia has info on some (can't remember the page) however it seems to suggest that some Beta Bosses were changed on release

Comment: Didn't he also mention during the fight the weapon used when low hp was different, it wasn't a nōdachi? That was why he called out the warning to begin with as I recall. By that statement, he couldn't have known the skills because the boss wasn't even using a nōdachi like the book the beta testers wrote said. It seemed like a plot hole that no one but Kirito noticed it wasn't a nōdachi, but a talwar, being a life or death fight and all.

Comment: The information about the weapon are a nōdachi comes from the book from beta testers. That's because on these floor on beta test, that's the weapon used. Kirito only noticed it, maybe talwar isn't used on a boss on beta test, only on some semi-boss on the floor, or noone of the tester who defeat the boss using talwar on the beta are on the fight with the 1st floor boss. If you read, aparently, only two testers are on these fight, diabel (who are apparently waiting for the last attack bonus) and Kirito.

Answer (score 5):

He was a Beta Tester. Klein identified Kirito as one in the first episode before Kayaba trapped all the players. The [Sword Art Online Wiki](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Klein#Aincrad_Arc) also confirms this:

> Early in the official version of the game, he noticed and identified Kirito as a beta tester, and asked to be taught the basics of fighting.

However, what Kirito was lying about was **how far he got** during the Beta testing phase. In fact, he only got to the 10th floor during the Beta, which was about as far any of the Beta Players got:

> One of the lucky 1000 players accepted into the closed-beta, Kirito logged hundreds of hours of playtime. He, along with the other top players, were able to reach the 10th Floor before the beta had ended.

Source: [Kirito: Sword Art Online Closed Beta](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Kirito#Sword_Art_Online_Closed_Beta)

Also, the article on [Beta Tester](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Beta_Tester) says

> The beta period lasted until the August 31, 2022 and the beta testers managed to reach the 10th Floor by the end of the beta.

In both instances, it says that they *reached* the 10th floor, not cleared it.

---

However, as cited in my question that you link to, during the scene, Kirito claimed that (emphasis mine):

> **Kirito:** **I** made it to floors **not even the other Beta players** could reach.

What he claimed contradicts with the information from the Wiki, so I think Kirito is lying about his progress.

Also Kirito seemed to be out of character when he acted stuck up and looked down at the other Beta Players as he compared himself to them and accepted the term Beater. So while Kirito is one of the top Beta Players, I believe he was lying about his own progress during this scene<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup> This is based on watching the anime. I have not read the light novels.</sup>

Comment: technically i'm not sure if this is actually a lie, considering the original said 6th floor and the author amended it to the 10th floor later. The important part is that this was the **1st** floor boss, so technically, he made it waaaay higher either way you look at it. The other part of the question is if he made it further than anyone else, which I don't know.

Comment: @ton.yeung on the Wiki i link to the reference says *"Volume 1 said that it was the 6th Floor, but this was retconned to the 10th in the Progressive version of the story."*, i liked to hope a Wiki's references are correct

Comment: I'm not saying that the wiki is wrong, what I'm saying is that there is no proof that Kirito lied about anything.

Comment: I edited the question a bit to clarify what I'm getting at.  Basically, the dubbed version implies something which I didn't get from the subbed version, and I haven't seen the novel form to know how that weighs in.

Comment: I always figured that, if he was lying, he was doing so to focus more ire on himself than other testers.  "Screw those other guys, I'm the top player.  I'm the one holding out on everybody."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kirito did lie. Before Klein tried to log out, he said that he reached till floor 8 in 2 months. About the term "beater" in the extra edition of SAO, the guy said that he accepted his fate just to keep other beta testers from being hated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that he lied in that scene because he wanted to get all the hate towards him. He must've did that to make betas not receive so much hate. But, he could have meant he leveled up wayyyy higher then other betas. Though I still think he did that to make the betas receive less hate and not to brag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have an idea. This was the beta, right? So wouldn't there be bugs? What if he wasn't lying about advancing past other beta testers? What if he found a glitch a way to pass floors with nothing stopping him?

Also what if he fought the bosses, but merely got them low and claimed he beat them. But just before killing the boss he would leave, but not without reward. Because that reward would be knowing how to fight and beat the bosses. The boss would live to continue keeping the gate closed for other testers. So perhaps he did go to other floors farther above. And since it's the beta, the bosses may be easier to fight. They may have the same abilities in the alpha but their attack damage and maybe attack speed had increased. Or maybe more HP and less damage but maybe the room itself worked against you. Like hidden traps for the boss to push or somehow get you into.

So, in conclusion, I believe that he *did* make it way higher than other beta testers but in a way that made it impossible for them to progress without finding that glitch. Being able to advance levels just before killing the boss. Maybe even acquiring new items. I don't believe that you'd get a plethora of items at the start of the game. But seeing as he said previously that he was imagining item builds means that he may have more items then just beginner items.

Answer (score 0):

I believe he made this statement to try and remove the hate towards other Beta testers and direct it at himself.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe he did actually get higher than the other beta testers. In the anime when Kirito claims that he made it to higher floors than any other beta tester it shows a map of Aincrad flying by in the background. As the map pans by you can count the floor levels highlighted in red. If you count the floors it ends up at the 29th floor. This appears that if he was saying he went to higher floors than any other beta tester he wound up on the 29th floor without passing it. Although this does not confirm if he really did end up on the 29th floor or not, I think it can be assumed that he is claiming he went to the 29th floor.

This also maybe just a cool background that the anime chose to show to represent the idea that he has made it to high levels.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! While we all appreciate your contribution it's better *not* to answer old posts when you have nothing to add or contradict. It's also better to include relevant sources and/or information in your answer.

Comment: That's essentially impossible, based on SAO rules and info from LN / Anime / Wiki. If one player can go to one floor, then, all players can go to these floor. If you read my answer you can understand this better.